# PySpark: How to specify file size when writing parquet files?

Tags: python, pyspark, bigdata, parquet

I have a 600+gb JSON that I want to convert to parquet. The syntax for reading and writing parquet is trivial:

Reading:

```
data = spark.read.parquet('file-path')
```

Writing:

```
data.write.parquet("file-path")
```

My question, though, is whether there's an option to specify the size of the resultant parquet files, namely close to 128mb, which according to Spark's documetnation is the most performant size. Currently doing `data.write.parquet` results in files between 10-20mb, which I suspect is affecting the performance of my jobs.

I've tried to use `coalesce`, as in `data.coalesce(1500).write.mode("append").parquet("file-path")` as a workaround, but setting the partition number is somewhat hit-or-miss.

Is there a better way of writing to parquet?

Comment: Use Repartition or --conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=100

Your performance may be impacted if you use repartition,Coalesce doesn't shuffle the data as much as repartition do, but repartition effectively guarantee same sized files in the output.. you can decide based on your input what shuffle partition or repartition needed.  But i am doubtful if it will increase the performance though

Comment: @Rafa thanks will check out